# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'channel' discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, discord.py

I am trying to create a function that would clear the chat on discord using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBVaH6nToyM , however I think that I've declared channel (`channel = ctx.message.channel`) however entering `.clear` would result in an error

```
Ignoring exception in command clear
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in 
wrapped
ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:/Users/mark/Desktop/purge.py", line 17, in clear
await client.delete_message(messages)
File "C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1261, in delete_message
channel = message.channel
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'channel
```

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
TOKEN = "token here"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print("Bot is online")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
     channel = ctx.message.channel
     messages = []
     async for message in client.logs_from(channel,limit=int(amount)):
         messages.append(messages)
     await client.delete_message(messages)
     await client.say('message has been deleted')

  client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You pass a *list* of messages to ``delete_message``, not a single one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how do i pass it in such a way that it would be able to clear a list?

Comment: Why not clear each message individually?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Tried but still gives the same error as mentioned above, mind suggesting which part of the code that needs to be rectified? Thanks

Comment: There are two coroutines for deleting messages, `delete_message` and [`delete_messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_messages).  Use the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically appending a list itself over and over again

```py
my_list=[]
my_list.append(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

Which results in something like this

```py
>>[[[...]]
```

The command should be something like this

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clear(msg,amt:int=20): #can be converted into int via :type
    messages=[]
    async for i in bot.logs_from(msg.message.channel,limit=amt):
        messages.append(i)
    await bot.delete_messages(messages)
```

Also a heads up note, you can't bulk delete messages that are older than 14 days I think meaning that you can't use the `delete_messages` and only delete it individually